# Swagger API - multiple @ApiImplicitParam for JSON POST

Tags: json, rest, post, swagger

I am trying to create my first REST app and I am using Swagger to document and test it. My controller receives POST in JSON:

```
"body": {
  "search_query" : "text",
  "page" : 1
}
```

I thought I can annotate controller like this:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name="search_query",value="Text to search for",required = false,dataType = "String",paramType = "body"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name="page",value="Page number",required = true,dataType = "int",paramType = "body")
})
```

But generated curl looks like this:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '1' 'http://localhost:9000/api/search'
```

And this is not what I am looking for.. , then I found out I can not have 2 body parameters. But how do I annotate my controller then , if I do not want to create class for this data and annotate it with model?